# Console Application C# no Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Baixei o VS 2017 e estou com problemas, não consigo trabalhar com o Console Application. Inicio o programa e faço o seguinte:

1. **Arquivo**
2. **Novo Projeto**
3. **Aplicação em C#**

Aparecem várias opções para trabalhar com a linguagem porém nenhuma delas mostra a opção de "Console Application C#", alguém pode me informar o motivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você se certificou de ter instalado o pacote `.NET`na hora de instalar o Visual Studio? Mesmo que trabalhe com C#, se for usar o console application vai precisar do pacote `.NET` instalado. 
[image: Certifique de ter essa opção selecionada]

Você pode verificar isso abrindo o instalador `.exe`, que vai te mostrar essa tela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em modificar e você verá todos os packs instalados, caso o `.NET` não esteja selecionado é só marcar e instalar :)